# Show that if $D$ is a dense subset in $[0, π]$, then $\sin(D)$ is dense in $[0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Working my way through my first topology course. Would anyone be able to break this example down for me? We were never shown anything concrete like this to work with, just abstract intuition, so I don't really know how to start...

This is the definition of dense we were given: Let $X$ be a metric space, $A \subseteq X$ and $D \subseteq A$. $D$ is dense in $A$ if for every $a \in A$ and $r > 0$, $B(a, r) \cap D$ is non-empty.

Comment: If $f : X \to Y$ is continuous and if $A \subset X$, we always have $f\left( \overline{A}\right) \subset \overline{f(A)}$. Apply this to $f = \sin$ and $A = D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y \in [0,1]$. Then  there exists $x \in [0,\pi]$ such that $\sin x =y$. There is  sequence $(d_n)$ in $D$ converging to $x$. Now $\sin d_n -y\to \sin x-y=0$. This proves that $\{\sin d: d\in D\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

In general continuous surjective functions map dense sets to dense sets.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing we need is that the function is continuous: if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and onto and $D$ is dense in $X$, $f[D] = \{f(d)\mid d \in D\}$ is dense in $Y$.

Let $y \in Y$ and $r>0$, for some $x \in X$, $f(x)=y$ and by continuity at $x$ there is some $\delta >0$ so that $$x' \in B(x,\delta) \to f(x') \in B(f(x),r)$$ Now we can pick $d \in D$ with $d \in B(x,\delta)$ ($D$ is dense) and then the continuity condition gives that $f(d) \in B(y,r) \cap f[D]$. So $f[D]$ is dense.

Now use that $x \to \sin(x)$ is continuous and onto from $[0,\pi]$ to $[0,1]$.